# use directive using ng-if?

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I want trigger a button to do ng-show of an input bar then focus on it. To avoid complication I found this simple directive to do the focus.

```
app.directive('autoFocus', function($timeout) {
    return {
        restrict: 'AC',
        link: function(_scope, _element) {
            $timeout(function(){
                _element[0].focus();
            }, 0);
        }
    };
});

<input auto-focus type="text"/>
```

But now I don't know how to use it upon it appearing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using `ng-if` on input will solve your problem. Because if you use `ng-show`, it means that element is still part of page but not visible. But `ng-if` make new element when its condition get true. Run snippet and check for yourself.

```js
var app = angular.module("myApp",[]);
app.directive('autoFocus', function($timeout) {
    return {
        restrict: 'AC',
        link: function(_scope, _element) {
            $timeout(function(){
                _element[0].focus();
            }, 0);
        }
    };
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.23/angular.min.js"></script>
<div ng-app="myApp">
<button ng-click="showInput = true;" >Show Input</button>
<button ng-click="showInput = false;" >Hide Input</button>  
<input auto-focus type="text" ng-if="showInput">
</div>
```

This way when button make input appear, you can see by typing that it is focused on that.
Quoting from ngif [documentation](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngIf)

> The ngIf directive removes or recreates a portion of the DOM tree
>   based on an {expression}. If the expression assigned to ngIf evaluates
>   to a false value then the element is removed from the DOM, otherwise a
>   clone of the element is reinserted into the DOM.